# Delete child from firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I use following code to add a child and set a value to it in FireBase.

```
 String ref = Constants.Client+"/"+Constants.firebaseProjects+"/"+Constants.ProjectName+"/xyz";
 final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseRefer);
 ref.child("mockChild").push().setValue("")
```

What can I do to delete the "mockChild" ?

Answer (score 14):

```
ref.child("mockChild").removeValue();
```

Code to add child - `ref.child("mockChild").push().setValue("Hello");`

[image: Added child]

Code to remove child - `ref.child("mockChild").removeValue();`

[image: Removed image]

Lets take an example in a user db:

```
ref.child("Users").child("User1").setvalue("User 1");
ref.child("Users").child("User2").setvalue("User 2");
ref.child("Users").child("User3").setvalue("User 3");
```

Now if you want to remove a specific user from the database you have to use this code:

```
ref.child("Users").child("User2").removeValue();
```

Since firebase is a key value database, it will remove the value from User2 and also the key since the key can't be on it's own. This will remove the entire reference to User2 from your database.

Comment: Will it not just remove the value in this case the "" , I want to delete the entire child.

Comment: It should remove the value, and when the value is removed, the key will be removed with it :)

Comment: Are you sure that when value is removed the key will be removed? Because internally what the method does is that it will set a null object to the value.

Comment: Edited my answer, so you can see what happens, it removes the key if value has been removed

Comment: where does -Kv2Nv.. come from?

Comment: Random value, since nothing is specified, if you want to specify something you need to add another child.

ref.child("mockChild").child("Key name here").setValue("The value");

Comment: Then you can remove that value by doing ref.child("mockChild").child("The key you want to remove").removeValue();

Comment: Ok, got it...
But why is it not coming like this:-
mockChild : "Hello"
Why is it creating another child?

Comment: Thats just the way firebase handles it :) Firebase can't have empty keys, so the first child you make is kind of your main table. Then you can add more keys + values under here :)

Comment: This is not my first child.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
String key = ref.child("mockChild").push().getKey();
ref.child("mockChild").child(key).setValue("yourValue");
ref.child("mockChild").child(key).removeValue(); // This is how you remove it
```

or you can use:

```
ref.child("mockChild").child(key).setValue(null);
```

It's also accepted and means that when you give Firebase a null value for a property/path, you indicate that you want to property or path to be deleted.

If you want to remove the entire child, then just use:

```
ref.child("mockChild").removeValue();
```

Note, it will remove everything that `mockChild` contains.

Comment: I dont want to change the value in the child, I want to remove the child it self.

Comment: I don't change the value. I just showed you how to set a value using `setValue()` method and then how to remove the same value using `removeValue()` method. Does it work? You only need to use `removeValue()` directly o the reference.

Comment: Please see also my updated answer.