# How to delete the individual childs from firebase in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I went through various links and solutions [delete-child-from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46448145/delete-child-from-firebase),  [How to remove child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185620/how-to-remove-child-nodes-in-firebase-android?noredirect=1&lq=1) and try to use in my project but nothing works.As following the link [Deletion of child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361440/how-to-delete-a-specific-child-from-firebase-java),

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("calendario").child("-L7jrJ6DtQWrmZsC4zvT").removeValue();
```

it works on the case where key is not generated which is not mine case.Database Structure is here.

[image]

Following piece of Code is for deletion of individual child which I have tried.
Any help is appreciated.

```
 delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            FirebaseDatabase ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference myRef = ref.getReference("Students");
            String key = myRef.push().getKey();
             myRef.child(key).removeValue(); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: is your code not deleting the push key?

Comment: I am a little confused. `push()` will create a new key and `removeValue` will delete it.  You have to pass the key that you want to delete somewhere.

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes Sir

Comment: @VinayAvasthi Sir,how can I modify this code?

Comment: @VinayAvasthi I have tried to delete like this, but not having deletion ,help me.https://codeshare.io/5MPWKQ

Comment: You have to tell how are you populating the values. I assume `delete` is a button. On the UI how does the user select what to delete? Are you using RecyclerView or something else?

Comment: @VinayAvasthi Sir,  that is delete button and I am using RecyclerView.I cannot solved this till today,the attached link contains the code of adapter class.I am new to firebase.https://codeshare.io/5X08Bz

Comment: You should keep the key in CustomAdapter and MyHolder classes. I see that you have a Student class. What I prefer is that I also keep the key in Student class. That way when you are registering the listener for `delete` you will have access to the key. The CustomAdapter has a list of Students, you add key as attribute in Student and populate when you create a new item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `push()`, you are generating a new random id, then when you use `removeValue()` on that key it will lead to deleting that key.

If you want to delete an existing key in your database, then you need to retrieve it from the database to be able to use it with `removeValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't deleting anything because you are only generating a new key. If you want to delete an existing key, please use the following line of code:

```
ref.getReference("Students").child("-LaFeagvdt-mLlc2eWeV").removeValue();
```

The result will be the deletion of the second record.

Comment: Sir,keys are generated in random ways,so it might be a difficult job to store  every keys which are randomly generated, and store them in the variable form ,for the deletion options.Is there other ways ??

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787784/how-to-get-specific-pushedid-in-firebase/51788244)** out.

Comment: This updates the randomly generated id but I cannot know how to use this for deletion help me!.https://codeshare.io/5DNgNl

Comment: (I have tried this code for deletion but didnot work).
                    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    String studentId = rootRef.child("Students").push().getKey();
                    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("studentId", studentId);
                    rootRef.child("Students").child(studentId).removeValue();

Comment: Again I have tried to delete like this, but not having deletion ,help me.https://codeshare.io/5MPWKQ

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the key of the child you want to delete in some variable. Let's assume it is in a variable keyToBeDeleted.

```
String keyToBeDeleted = "-LaFeagvdt-mLlc2eWeV";
 delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        FirebaseDatabase ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = ref.getReference("Students/" + keyToBeDeleted);
        myRef.removeValue();
    }
});
```

Comment: Sir,keys are generated in random ways,so it might be a difficult job to store  every keys which are randomly generated, and store them in the variable form ,for the deletion options.Is there other ways ??

Comment: You need to keep track of which key you want to delete. When You are listing items for deletion, at that time you will have access to those keys and then depending on which button you click on, you need to use that key to delete it.

Comment: Would you please suggest me on programs, to implement this logic?